# Connectivity of SonarLite from STS

Tags: sonarqube, sts

I have standalone application. When I try to connect to sonarqube I am getting be below error
"sonarqube server has version 5.6.7 version should be greater or equal to 6.7"

[image]

C

Answer (score 0):

The following refers to the IntelliJ plugin, but the issues are the same: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/incompatible-sonarqube-server-version-error/15820 .